# Unable to connect to Postgres within docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

So I'm trying to dockerize my Postgres-Express-React-Node Application the docker-compose for the application is

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:12.1
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: PGAdminAth

    backend:
        build: ./backend
        container_name: backend_c
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./backend:/app
        ports:
            - "4000:4000"
    frontend:
        build: ./frontend
        container_name: frontend_c
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
```

but every time I run `docker-compose up`, I get

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
backend_c   |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16) {
backend_c   |   errno: -111,
backend_c   |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
backend_c   |   syscall: 'connect',
backend_c   |   address: '127.0.0.1',
backend_c   | }
```

as an error.

The piece of code that connects to my postgres database from nodejs app is

```
const { Client } = require("pg");

const client = new Client({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  user: "postgres",
  password: "PGAdminAth",
  database: "postgres",
});

client.connect();
```

Comment: change localhost for postgres as a host, it should work, more here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 1):

Docker-compose configures a virtual network where all the containers from compose file live. This:

```yaml
postgres: # <--- This
    image: postgres:12.1
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: PGAdminAth
```

means that any service within the virtual network will be able to reach your database by hostname `postgres`.

So your client code have to use service names when perform network communication to the container.

Hence your client setup would be

```
const client = new Client({
  host: "postgres",
  port: 5432,
  user: "postgres",
  password: "PGAdminAth",
  database: "postgres",
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `depends_on` in the `backend` service. (This started the Database before the `backend` service.)

```
depends_on:
    - postgres
```

---

And  change this

```
host: "localhost",
```

to this

```
host: "postgres",
```

Inside the application, containers refer to their service name. So use the service name that you gave when defining Database. Examples of service names postgres, backend, and frontend.

---

> To store Database data permanently, you must map a volume to it. [Read this](https://geshan.com.np/blog/2021/12/docker-postgres/)